# How to aggs nested attribute per document

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I use elastic search for user search. I have a document like this.

```
{
   "uid":1,
   "fullname": "xxxx",
   "order_info": [
      {"order_id":1, "create_time":"2018-01-01"},
      {"order_id":2, "create_time":"2019-01-01"},
      {"order_id":3, "create_time":"2019-02-01"}
    ]
}
```

Can I get the document like this sql

```
select * from member_info where id in (
  select member_id from order_info where create_time > '2019-01-01' group by 
  uid having count(*) > 3
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Post Filter Aggregation.

1. Use a query to filter order_info with create_time
2. Use a value aggregation on the above query to count the number of orders in order_info
3. Use a post_filter query to get the results when the count is grater than

OR

Simply use Elasticsearch SQL REST API
[image: elasticsearch sql rest API]

References:

- [Post Filter Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html)
- [Value Count Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html)
- [SQL REST API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-rest.html)

Comment: The result I want is the main document. can you show me the full query dsl?

Comment: I do not have an elastic search setup up and running with the data. Moreover, I encourage you to try the elasticsearch query yourself and I can help you debug the query.